# Laravel 5.4 Multi-Auth nginx passing attempt, not authenticating

Tags: laravel, authentication, nginx, middleware

I have a multi authorization system working in my development environment, however when I migrated to production, it does not want to work.

In running this on the production server, I can return the boom statement when it is enabled.

My development environment is Apache while my production is Nginx.

I have also included below the previous error that I get my error log.  Previously, it was also giving me a too many redirects error

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
     switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {   
            return redirect()->route('admin');
                     }          
          break;

        default:
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {    
            return redirect('/user');
          }
          break;
      }


use App\models\admin\admin_user;
class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()    {      $this->middleware('guest:admin');    }

    public function showLoginForm()    {      return view('auth.admin_login');    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
      // Validate the form data
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remembe$
//      return "Boom";
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin'));
      }

      // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
      return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

namespace App\models\admin;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class admin_user extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard='admin';
    protected $table='admin_users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','type','nLogins','isOnline','lastOnline','timeOnline'
    ];

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
          case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.login';
            break;

          default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
}

production.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::$headers in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:156
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(156): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/www/larave...', 156, Array)
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->addCookieToResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException))
#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

Admin_login

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
```